# Help designing a Bluetooth controlled square wave generator

Tags: pcb-design, bluetooth

I am an EE student, and I am working on my first quasi-freelance project.
I am designing a PCB, and part of the design requirements is a square wave generator whose frequency is controlled by a Bluetooth receiver. I need a range of 20-1000 Hz. I know electronic circuit theory, but I have never worked with Bluetooth protocol before, and I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a commercial Bluetooth module that encapsulates the stack, read and understand all the application notes and datasheet. It will act more-or-less as a wireless serial port.

Implement the serial-port-controlled square wave generator with whatever technology is appropriate for the performance requirements- microcontroller with on-board peripherals, aux DDS or whatever.

If you are planning to sell this, read up on the license and other fees to use BT.

Answer (score 0):

There are some Bluetooth modules which have widespread support by online communities. Eg. For [HC-05 module](https://wiki.eprolabs.com/index.php?title=Bluetooth_Module_HC-05) you will find many readily working online projects/codes which will make your development easier. Other modules are mentioned [Here](https://www.intorobotics.com/pick-right-bluetooth-module-diy-arduino-project/) .

If you want to go into depth and understand working of Bluetooth protocol on multiple layers, you can refer to its [core specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification) on its official [website](http://www.bluetooth.com).

You can also refer to the first chapter of this [book](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rudolph/Teaching/Articles/BTBook-march.pdf) for brief understanding of protocol.